# GAE python: not refresing source code on deployment

Tags: python, google-app-engine, backend

I have an error in GAE python API with my app.

Error is:

File "/base/data/home/apps/s~graph-coloring/coloring.362739865286670993/main.py", line 249, in txn
    Gfile.put()

I have dropped the txn function but it still appears. I have changed also app version, deployed several times but GAE is still calling txn function.

What can be the problem?
I am running the handler in a backend

I have tested on dev-server and it works.

**Note:**
It seems that each backend has its own copy of the app? So in order to deploy the app you need also to update each backend? it seems that doing this solved my problem.

Can someone confirm this?

```
2012-10-27 15:43:35.901

invalid handle: 11954713935722084435
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~graph-coloring/coloring.362739865286670993/main.py", line 252, in post
    db.run_in_transaction(txn,key,alpha)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 2433, in RunInTransaction
    return RunInTransactionOptions(None, function, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 2571, in RunInTransactionOptions
    ok, result = _DoOneTry(new_connection, function, args, kwargs)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 2593, in _DoOneTry
    result = function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~graph-coloring/coloring.362739865286670993/main.py", line 249, in txn
    Gfile.put()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1074, in put
    return datastore.Put(self._entity, **kwargs)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 579, in Put
    return PutAsync(entities, **kwargs).get_result()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 604, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1569, in __put_hook
    self.check_rpc_success(rpc)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1224, in check_rpc_success
    raise _ToDatastoreError(err)
BadRequestError: invalid handle: 11954713935722084435
```

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3643#c8 for a discussion on a similar error.

Comment: i am experiencing a similar problem. But it's in my localhost. Once an error is shown, even after removing the entire line of that error it still shows the same error. It gets solved once i turn off GAE and restart GAE. This is a pain.